# Android - Center text inside EditText programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-xml

I'm writing a custom Android view which contains an EditText. I want to be able to center the text vertically through Java code but it's not working.

[image: My failure]

As you can see from the image above, the text is not centering vertically. I set the EditText background to a light red so you can see the layout bounds of it. I have an EditText on the left of it rendered through XML code and it it working correctly.

How do I get the text to show correctly?

.

Here is my code for the middle EditText:

```
txtSearch = new EditText(context);
txtSearch.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1f));
txtSearch.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
txtSearch.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.nowl_red_transparent_12));//Color.TRANSPARENT);
txtSearch.setHint("Search");
txtSearch.setHintTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.text_hint));
txtSearch.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
txtSearch.setMaxLines(1);
txtSearch.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
txtSearch.setTypeface(Typeface.create("sans-serif-light", Typeface.NORMAL));
txtSearch.setTextSize(16f);
txtSearch.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
txtSearch.setText("Y u no center");
container.addView(txtSearch);
```

and here is the code for the EditText on the left which renders correctly:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:hint="test" />
```

I tried practically everything. I used `setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL)`, removed/added properties, and more. Nothing of which worked. Is this a bug with Android or is there something I'm missing here? It looks like this in the UI Preview and in actual Android devices as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of it, it does look aligned to some degree. If it was top aligned, it would be on the far top with maybe 1dp of margin. If it was bottom aligned, it would be so high either.

I drew a green box on top of your original image to show what I think is what it is aligned relative to.

[image: Padding box]

Given you have replaced the original background with a custom color, It might be possible that Android is pulling some unexpected default settings either from your context object or the system defaults and adds a padding (although I don't remember Android having any padding by default). Have you tried `txtSearch.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0)` just in case?

Answer (score 1):

It works well on my side with your code. The only difference is I don't know what is your contain like.
My advice is :

1. Try to remove the white background image which must be a 9 patch image
2. Open your device's developer options: `Settings`->`Developer Options`->`Show layout bounds` to debug your view. In this way, it'll be much easier for you to debug.

---

[image]

Comment: Turns out my EditText was inheriting some padding from my context. Probably due to the AppCompat library I'm using.

Comment: Cool. Turn on your `Show layout bounds` when debug view will make your life better. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, using the Show layout bounds option makes padding look like part of the actual view. It didn't help much here. :/

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:gravity="top"` attribute to your EditText in the xml file.

[How do I place the text inside an EditText widget at the top?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832388/center-typed-text-in-edittext)

Comment: The one in the XML file is centered correctly, I need to center the one created via Java vertically.

Comment: Sorry... You might need to use WRAP_CONTENT for your layout. That should do it... If not, I have no clue.

Comment: Al right. Let's try hack it... First get your params to fill_parent and wrap_content and try again... Finally try this either 1 by 1 or all together and see if any of them make a difference, if it doesn't, you must be defining it twice somehow...

`txtSearch.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
and 
txtSearch.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
and 
txtSearch.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
and 
txtSearch.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
and
txtSearch.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
and 
txtSearch.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
and 
txtSearch.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);`